# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class com.google.gwt.dev.HostedModeBase$ArgHandlerNoServerFlag

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gwt-2.7

I am trying to upgrade my application from GWT 2.0 to 2.7.0 and getting below exception. I am using the below mentioned jars. What is the reason for this exception ? Is there any migration guide or document that i can refer for upgrading to 2.7 gwt version ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class com.google.gwt.dev.HostedModeBase$ArgHandlerNoServerFlag overrides final method getPurpose.()Ljava/lang/String;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

**Jars used :**

gwt-user-2.7.0.jar

get-dev-2.7.0.jar

gwt-servlet-2.7.0.jar

gwt-dev-windows.jar

gwtext.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gwt-dev-windows.jar` is an old dependency from pre-2.0 GWT (you should have already removed it when updating to 2.0 a while ago), and it conflicts here with the newer `gwt-dev-2.7.0.jar`.

BTW, unless you want to continue using "classic DevMode", you'll also need `gwt-codeserver-2.7.0.jar`.

Last, but not least, you'll likely have to update your GWT-Ext dependency as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help..I removed the gwt-dev-windows.jar and added gwt-codeserver-2.7.0.jar but i am getting "ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell" Exception.

Comment: Yes indeed; in GWT 1.6, GWTShell was deprecated in favor of HostedMode, and in 2.0 HostedMode was deprecated in favor of DevMode. Those old entry-points have been removed since then. So just like you should have removed `gwt-dev-windows.jar` when updating to 2.0 a while ago, you should have also switched to DevMode.